# Why is the or-Matcher not working in my Mockito verify?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I would like to verify that either of the following two method calls get executed once:

```java
myLogger.logWarn("My 1st Warning Message"); // depending on some randomness in my program,
myLogger.logWarn("My 2nd Warning Message"); // one of these two get executed
```

I have tried the following:

```java
verify(myLogger).logWarn(or("My 1st Warning Message", "My 2nd Log Warning Message"));
```

But running the test method resulted in the following error:

```
No matchers found for additional matcher Or(?)
-> at foobar.builder.StopBuilderTest.build(StopBuilderTest.java:141)

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
No matchers found for additional matcher Or(?)
-> at foobar.builder.StopBuilderTest.build(StopBuilderTest.java:141)
```

When I just test for a single method call as follows..

```java
verify(myLogger).logWarn("My 1st Warning Message");
```

..it runs fine and my test is always successful when `logWarn()` gets called with argument `"My 1st Warning Message"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AdditionalMatchers](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html#or(short,%20short)) are used to implement common logical operations (‘not', ‘and', ‘or') on [ArgumentMatchers](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html)

So following code:

```
 verify(myLogger).logWarn(or(eq("My 1st Warning Message"), eq("My 2nd Log Warning Message")));
```

Should work as expected.

Comment: This is indeed working. Thank you very much for your clear and concise explanation!